# C++ ncurses encoding (UTF-8) troubles

Tags: c++, console, ncurses

When i'm running this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ncurses.h"

using namespace std;

std::string getstring()
{
    std::string input;
    nocbreak();
    echo();
    int ch = getch();
    while ( ch != '\n' )
    {
        input.push_back( ch );
        ch = getch();
    }
    return input;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    initscr();
    getstring();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

and typing `ФЫВФЫВ` (Russian) terminal shows me:

`M-Q~DM-Q~KM-PM-2M-Q~DM-Q~KM-PM-2`. This problem is only when i'm running ncurses, I mean if I run `std::cout << "ФЫВФЫВ";` I will see: `ФЫВФЫВ`

My `locale` output:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Ubuntu 15.04.

How can I fix it?

Comment: could you show how you link ncurses?

Comment: @ArneKjetilAndersen `g++ main.cpp -lncurses`

Comment: I'm not on ubuntu, but on arch linux i have the library ncursesw which is the one supporting utf8, check and see if you have that on your system, and then try linking against that.

Comment: @ArneKjetilAndersen yes, i found this library on another forums, but it didn't help me, same problems

Comment: The program worked as intended when compiled and linked with ncursesw; it is likely that you made an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
std::wstring c;
std::getline(std::wcin,c);
std::wcout << c;
```

instead of

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ncurses.h"

using namespace std;

std::string getstring()
{
    std::string input;
    nocbreak();
    echo();
    int ch = getch();
    while ( ch != '\n' )
    {
        input.push_back( ch );
        ch = getch();
    }
    return input;
}

int main() {
    std::wstring c;
    std::getline(std::wcin,c);
    std::wcout << c;
    initscr();
    getstring();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```